# CSS: menu is displayed with right space in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, menu, space

I have just started with CSS and have created a dropdown menu. Everything looks good in Chrome and IE, but with Firefox I run into two problems:

1) The gradient is not the light green as in Chrome or IE, but a heavier/darker grey.

2) The menu is displayed with an extra 7px on the right side. These 7px are not just empty space, as it has the background of my `nav ul` element, but it is not part of (though maybe caused by) any `li` elements.

Regarding the second issue, I have found that Firefox adds space around `li` elements, and I therefore added comment codes before and after the `li` elements in the HTML code. Do I need to adjust my margin, padding or display in my CSS instead?

Hope someone can help me out here!

HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul><!--
--><li><a class="MenuLinks" href="#">About Us</a><!--
        --><ul><!--
            --><li><a href="#">Mission & Vision</a></li><!--
            --><li><a href="#">How Do We Contribute?</a></li><!--
            --><li><a href="#">History</a></li><!--
        --></ul><!--
--></li><!--
--><li><a class="MenuLinks" href="#">Renewable Energy</a><!--
            --><ul><!--
            --><li><a href="#">What is Renewable Energy?</a></li><!--
            --><li><a href="#">The Future of Renewable Energy</a></li><!--                
            --><li><a href="#">Towards Sustainable Living</a></li><!--
        --></ul><!--
--></li><!--
--><li><a class="MenuLinks" href="#">Our Projects</a><!--
        --><ul><!--
            --><li><a href="#">Current Projects</a></li><!--
            --><li><a href="#">Past Projects</a></li><!--
        --></ul><!--
--></li><!--
--><li><a class="MenuLinks" href="#">Education</a><!--
        --><ul><!--<!--
            --><li><a href="#">ALTENER Education</a></li><!--
            --><li><a href="#">Learning Materials</a></li><!--
            --><li><a href="#">Partners in Education</a></li><!--
        --></ul><!--
--></li><!--
--><li><a class="MenuLinks" href="#">How to Participate</a><!--
        --><ul><!--
            --><li><a href="#">Make a Donation</a></li><!--
            --><li><a href="#">Volunteer with Us</a></li><!--
            --><li><a href="#">Become a Partner</a></li><!--
        --></ul><!--
--></li><!--
--><li><a class="MenuLinks" href="#">Contact Us</a><!-- 
--></li><!--
--></ul>
</nav></td>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul ul {
display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 30%, #c8dc9a 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent 30%, #c8dc9a 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 30%, #c8dc9a 100%); 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, transparent 30%, #c8dc9a 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, transparent 30%, #c8dc9a 100%);
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-size: 16px; 
text-indent: 7px;
white-space: nowrap;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
display: inline-block;
}

nav ul:after {
    content: ""; 
    clear: both; 
    display: block;
}

nav ul li {
float: left;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #244612;
}

/* Set hover properties for main menu items */
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #e29a0e;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, #e29a0e 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, #e29a0e 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, #e29a0e 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, #e29a0e 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, #e29a0e 100%);
}
    nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #000000;
    }
    nav ul li:hover ul li a{
        color: #757575;
    }
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 13px;
    color: #757575; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Set general properties for dropdown menu items */    
nav ul ul {
background: #F7F7F7; 
border-radius: 0px; 
padding: 0;
position: absolute; 
top: 100%;
font-size: 14px;
}
/* Set hover properties for dropdown menu items */  
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #C9CCCF;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #C9CCCF;
    position: relative;
}
    nav ul ul li a {
        padding: 10px 25px;
    }   
        nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
            background: #e29a0e;
            color: #000000;
        }
```

Comment: Whats the purpose of the comments in your HTML?

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? Linear-gradient is described by the W3C as only functioning between versions of Firefox 3.6 to 15.

Comment: @Michal They're used to eliminate whitespace.  http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @user3325344 Have you tried validating your CSS and HTML?

Comment: @Michal: Like cimmanon said, to eliminate whitespace. However, this didn´t have any effect.

Comment: @Adosi: Firefox 23. Do I need a different gradient for this?

Comment: @cimmanon: No, is this necessary when everything is working properly in IE and Chrome?

Comment: Validating should ALWAYS be your first step in debugging.  Every browser will accept some garbage code, but they won't always recover from it gracefully or even in the same way.

Comment: If all else fails you can use                                             @-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .selector {
     // Styles 
  }
}

Comment: @cimmanon: CSS and HTML are both validated now, problem persists. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

This is a flaw in Firefox's handling of the `transparent` keyword. It treats it the same as `rgba(0,0,0,0)`, so the colour goes from black to light green. (Of course the black is fully transparent at first, but halfway down the gradient it's already dark grey.)

So the solution is to use the transparent version of the end colour #c8dc9a for the start colour, in rgba form. This is  `rgba(200,220,154,0)`. Same for the popup items, where the colour becomes `rgba(226,154,14,0)`.

```css
nav ul {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(200,220,154,0) 30%, #c8dc9a 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(200,220,154,0) 30%, #c8dc9a 100%);
...
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #e29a0e;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(226,154,14,0) 0%, #e29a0e 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(226,154,14,0) 0%, #e29a0e 100%);
...
```

By the way, it's better to put the unprefixed version of the gradient style on the bottom, after all the vendor-prefixed ones. Only then can you be sure that a browser which can use the formally defined one, actually does.

2)

It's not the margin or the padding that refuses to play nice, it's the text-indent. So I removed it and added some padding and margins to the inner list, to ensure it kept looking the same way.

See [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/gy48q/5/).

Comment: amazing, thank you so much! I had been playing around with so many things (like whitespace in the list), never thought of the text-indent. Your solution is perfect!
I read somewhere along the way (can´t find the link) that certain versions of IE need the unprefixed version of the gradient style on the top in order to display the gradient correctly. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: I do know that certain versions of IE need the IE specific filter, something like `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorstr='#112233', endColorstr='#445566');` And that this has a special syntax for transparent colors. But I'm not sure about the order; my fiddle works as expected in IE10 (that is, OK) and IE9 (that is, not at all, since IE9 only knows about the filter one).

Comment: All right, you have been a great help! Thank you so much Lister!