# CSS before and after pseudo elements not working in Edge and IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, pseudo-element

I'm having issue to display a button with angled sides with css using :before and :after pseudo elements. It is working in Chrome and Firefox but not in Edge and IE 11.
What might be the problem?

```css
a { text-decoration: none }
.container { margin: 20px; }
.font-jos {
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.btn-ribbon {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 13px 11px;
  background-color: #b46b78;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn-ribbon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -10px;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 22px solid #b46b78;
    border-bottom: 22px solid #b46b78;
    border-left: 10px solid #fff0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.btn-ribbon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -10px;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 22px solid #b46b78;
    border-bottom: 22px solid #b46b78;
    border-right: 10px solid #fff0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="btn font-jos btn-ribbon">Read more</a>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/nidus/pen/gXJYLg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change `#fff0` to `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)` or `transparent` in your CSS `border-right: 10px solid transparent;` and `border-left: 10px solid transparent;`. It's not liking the formatting of the colors.

IE and Edge don't seem to support that format.

Here's a working example:

```css
a { text-decoration: none }
.container { margin: 20px; }
.font-jos {
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.btn-ribbon {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 13px 11px;
  background-color: #b46b78;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn-ribbon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -10px;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 22px solid #b46b78;
    border-bottom: 22px solid #b46b78;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}
.btn-ribbon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -10px;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 22px solid #b46b78;
    border-bottom: 22px solid #b46b78;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="btn font-jos btn-ribbon">Read more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: True - and the four-digit format is relatively new, so that's why Edge doesn't support it yet. But `#fff0` is not really the same colour as `#fff`. Use `rgba(255,255,255,0)` instead to match the OP's intent.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for pointing this out, the color is `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)`, so I've mentioned the color but replaced it with `transparent` in the CSS.

Comment: OK. In this case using `transparent` makes no difference, but take note that there are circumstances in which it does. The official definition for `transparent` says it's the same as `rgba(0,0,0,0)`, which is not the same as `rgba(255,255,255,0)`! See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21874887/1016716) for an example of where it can go wrong.